# Android Google Play Service Barcode scanner does not works on 1D (EAN13) barcodes

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-vision

I'm testing the Barcode API from [android-vision](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) repo (multi-tracker app) . But I can only scan the QR Codes, I would like to scan also 1D barcodes like EAN 13. How can i do this work well ??

Ps.: Also, I have tried to filter only scan EAN 13, but also does not works well.

Thanks,
   Marcelo Alves

Comment: See issue tracker for repo: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/7

Answer (score 4):

An issue identified is that the CameraSource class used for this app does not include an auto focus setting.  For some barcode formats, such as EAN 13, this reduces the detection rate.

We have recently open sourced the CameraSource class, and this includes an option for auto-focus.  We recommend that you use this version of CameraSource and enable auto-focus:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java

**Update:**

The CameraSource provided with Google Play Services 8.4 now has an auto focus option.